# Should I use blend or state or layer for jump?

Tags: unity, animation-states

I am very confused on unity animation system. Should I be using a blend or state or layer?

I need the following animations

- walk ( WASD )
- run ( shift + WASD )
- jump ( space )
- push/pull ( p)
- throw ( t )
- Hit ( h )
- Die

I think, state can be used but build a logic to do these animation will be challenging?
Could someone explain with above animation in consideration.

Comment: Are there any of these animations which need to play simultaneously? Like throwing while jumping or getting hit while running?

Comment: @Philipp Yes player can hit while running, waking or jumping.

Comment: Then you are going to need different layers for all the animations you want to play simultaneously.